# getting aliases from config by regular expression (bad separated)

Tags: regex, bash, config

I tried to get some aliases from a specific config file in a short bash script. The config looks like:

```
[other config]

[alias]
alias: command -o option
alias2: command -l 2
alias3: command -o option

[other config]
```

How would you get these aliases separated? I would prefer a output like this:

```
alias: command -o option
alias2: command -l 2
alias3: command -o option
```

I already did some bad stuff like getting line numbers and so on... 
Any Ideas? Would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using sed:

```
sed -n -e '/\[alias\]/,/\[.*\]/s/:/:/p'
```

This will print all lines between `[alias]` and the next line containing `[` and `]` that have a colon on them.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has a [`Config::GitLike`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-GitLike/) module that may come in handy for parsing that git config file.

Looking at the documentation, you want to do:

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use 5.010;
use Config::GitLike;

my $c = Config::GitLike->new(confname => 'config');
$c->load;

my $alias = $c->get( key => 'alias.alias' );
my $alias2 = $c->get( key => 'alias.alias2' );
my $alias3 = $c->get( key => 'alias.alias3' );

say "alias: $alias";
say "alias2: $alias2";
say "alias3: $alias3";
```

Comment: Thank you CanSpice! I got to solve this problem in my bash script and looking for some regex strings. Perhaps i can use config::gitlike to learn how to get these regex strings :)